# Issue with picture uploads

Tags: support, images

I just uploaded a picture here, and there seems to be an issue with it.

For me I can see it. The TS seems to not being able to view the picture.

[To draw the rectangle $R=[0, 2]\times [0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3401849/to-draw-the-rectangle-r-0-2-times-0-1/3401867?noredirect=1#comment6997631_3401867)

What can be done?

Comment: Do you have a problem viewing the picture?

Comment: If it helps, the picture is visible to me both on the post and when I click on it and it goes to imgur.  I'm in Europe; maybe the person with the issue is somewhere with some internet filtering going on?

Comment: @postmortes Thanks. Yeah, there might be an internet issue, or maybe a browser issue, so that the website is not 'trusted'?

Comment: What/who is the TS?

Comment: It might be that the person who cannot see the picture has the site `imgur.com` blocked in their browser.  I can see the hand-drawn graph as you presumably expected.  Stackexchange has an agreement with imgur to host images for us on something approximating a permanent basis.

Comment: @PeterPhipps TS = ThreadStarter I thought that is common internet slang.

Comment: @Cornman more commonly in professional settings that's the OP ( original poster) also these aren't so much threads as questions. Remember this is not a forum.